Access is denied issue seen when launching Developer command prompt for VS 2022
I am seeing a "Access is Denied" issue when launching Developer command prompt for VS 2022
I am trying to launch the prompt from Start Menu--> Developer command prompt for VS 2022 --> Run as Administrator
First I get the windows prompt with the below message:
"This App Cant run on your PC"
"find a version for your PC, Check with software publisher"
After I click on Ok, I see the prompt with the following message:
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.11.5
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
Access is denied.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise>

From what I have observed is that
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat tries calling internally the below command.
powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Import-Module '%~dp0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'; Send-VsDevShellTelemetry -NewInstanceType Cmd;}"

At this point is where we have the access issue
I have also observed the similar issue while launching one of the application cmd file
echo set Falcon Specific Environment variables / Toggles

rem Set environment variable SET_LOCALIP, which is used by many services.
rem #Remarks: If more network adapters are available, choose the one which has the Internet or other sl artifacts can be accessed.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command "(Get-NetIPAddress | Where InterfaceIndex -EQ ((Get-NetConnectionProfile | Where Name -like "*.sl.net").InterfaceIndex)).IPAddress"') do (
    set SET_LOCALIP=%%a
)

if not defined SET_LOCALIP (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -command "(Get-NetIPAddress -PrefixOrigin Dhcp | Where-Object {$_.ValidLifetime -Lt ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue) -and $_.AddressState -Eq 'Preferred'}).IPAddress"') do (
        set SET_LOCALIP=%%a
    )
)


Note: I am able to execute other PowerShell scripts independently.
Also, running the command independently works well when given the full path to PowerShell.exe
D:\OCT24A\bin\x64\Debug\devShell>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "(Get-NetIPAddress | Where InterfaceIndex -EQ ((Get-NetConnectionProfile | Where Name -like "*.sl.net").InterfaceIndex)).IPAddress"
 
D:\OCT24A\bin\x64\Debug\devShell>powershell.exe -command "(Get-NetIPAddress | Where InterfaceIndex -EQ ((Get-NetConnectionProfile | Where Name -like "*.sl.net").InterfaceIndex)).IPAddress"
Access is denied.


Try running As Admin.  Right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The start your cmdlet.

Did you try to run where powershell.exe to detect the location of powershell.exe installed on your machine?


This App Cant run on your PC" "find a version for your PC, Check with software publisher.

Looks like your powershell.exe used default by VS is invalid. Please open your command prompt and run the following command to detect the default locationn of powershell.exe
where powershell.exe

This will show the path to the PowerShell executable.
Please navigate to the path C:/windows/system32/ and check if powershell.exe file existsIf not, please navigate to this path C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ and copy the powershell.exe to the above folder.
Besides, you can run the following command to check execution Policy,if it's set to Restricted, change it to Unrestricted. Then reopen your Developer command prompt for VS 2022 to see if the issue persists.
Get-ExecutionPolicy

